# How can I make unskippable ads?(AdMob)

Tags: admob-rewardedvideoad

I'm working with AdMob rewarded ads, in the AdMob test rewarded ad the video length is 5 seconds, and after 5s a skip button appears, and I do have several questions:
Does all ad videos length will be 5 seconds?
Can I make unskippable ads?
Can I set the ad video skip time? (first one 15s, the other 30s...)

Comment: Just a reminder, you'd probably feel annoyed if you couldn't skip an ad. Check out https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/O9kWCxLYChk

Comment: @KTibow The main purpose is to increase incomes and my expectations is more seconds watching -> more money am I right? and I'm not thinking to make it 1 min, at maximum 30s

Comment: In my experience, if you skip the ad, you lose the reward. You can always record when you started the ad, and when the ad was finished, and see if the difference was big enough.